# invariants of plane quartics

Tags: reference-request, ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, geometric-invariant-theory

Does anybody know a good reference where the invariants for plane quartic curves are developed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check "Polar Covariants of Plane Cubics and Quartics" by Dolgachev and Kanev?

Comment: Ha! I had forgotten that paper, it is sure a good starting point. I'll take a look straight away, thank you.